# Not able to fetch Unique id of an item click on Listview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the unique id of an user from a click on an item in listview...
I tried using `datasnapshot.getKey` method but it's not happening
According to some Youtube videos `getRef(position).getKey();` Should work but thats showing cannot resolve symbol `getRef`... why is that?
Here's my code

```
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, al);
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                name = ds.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                list_user_id = ds.getKey();
                String user_id = getRef(position).getKey();
//                    Log.d("TAG", name);
                al.add(name);


            }
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please Check Your Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

`listuser = ds.getKey` method isnt working so i tried `getRef(position).getKey` but its not accepting... Someone help please

```
    usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            UserDetails.chatWith = al.get(position);
            String user_id = al.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
            intent.putExtra("visit_user_id",user_id);
            intent.putExtra("user_name",name);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
```

String userid returning name of the user.. idk y... if i put  list_user_id after "visit_user_id" its returning my own user id... can any1 atleast tell why the user id in the itemclick is returning name?

Comment: Firstly you have to implement onItemClickListener  if you want to get the position ..Have you tried it?

Comment: Look to my edited question plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the key, you need do it in the same way you get the name:

```
String user_id = ds.child("Id").getValue().toString();
```

Assuming that the `id` field in your database is called `Id`.

`getRef()` method returns a `DatabaseReference` object can can be called on a `DataSnapshot` object. Has nothing to do with this id.